# ¿Qué quiere decir "baracalofi"?

Tags: palabras-raras

En la novela "La lucha inútil" (Ramon Ayerra, 1984) he encontrado esta frase (negrita mía):
"Y curiosamente, en este vacile tan frecuente de topar los hechos desde perspectiva contraria, habían hallado un apañado reducto en el que distraerse y en el cual sentar las bases para el buen funcionamiento de su convivencia, y todo se reducía, en el caso del guardia Amancio Perona, a un forcejeo de mentirijillas, de **baracalofi**, porque en lo tocante al fondo de los problemas, a lo más profundo de las actitudes, era tan serio y tan hombre de bien como el Cabo, de lo que se enteró un metepatas el día en que, viéndole tan frescachón y tan relajado, tan parlón y tan guaseras, interpretó que el guardia tenía tragaderas tan amplias como las zorras ..."

No veo que **baracalofi** aparezca en el actual diccionario de la RAE, ni en los accesibles vía el NTLLE, ni  por el contexto me hago una idea de lo que significa.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que significa y de su origen?

Answer (score 2):

**De baracalofi**: gratis, de balde

> En efecto, en el árabe magrebí (también denominado dāriŷa, lengua fundamentalmente empleada en la comunicación oral y en el registro coloquial) la expresión religiosa **baracalofi** (bāraka llāhu fīk بارك الله فيك) posee literalmente el significado ‘que Dios te bendiga’. Además, esta misma expresión se utiliza, tanto en el registro formal como en el informal, para manifestar gratitud de una manera educada. Su frecuencia de uso es tal que ha llegado incluso a desplazar en parte a la voz gracias (šukran شكرا), que es más formal.
> Aunque los dos testimonios anteriores pertenecen a algunos de los civiles que vivieron durante algún tiempo en Marruecos, parece que quienes adoptaron la voz **baracalofi** y, en combinación con la preposición de, le dieron el uso que anunciábamos arriba (‘de balde’) fueron los soldados españoles presentes en el país africano durante el Protectorado español.

> ...un soldado veterano que estuvo en el acuartelamiento de Ifni antes de la Guerra Civil, publicó el 11 de septiembre de 2006 un texto llamado «La raza de los ifneños». Este militar asegura que todavía recuerda algunas palabras que servían a los soldados para comunicarse con los habitantes de Sidi Ifni. Entre estas palabras, se encuentra **baracalofi**, utilizada —afirma— para dar las gracias, y la locución **de baracalofi**, «para indicar que algo es gratis».

*Fuente [cvc.cervantes.es](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/busqueda/resultadosbusqueda.asp?Ver=50&Pagina=1&Titulo=De%20baracalofi&OrdenResultados=2)*